# How to get all possible value of a certain linux command?

Tags: linux, command, uname

For example, now I want to write a bash script in which I check the name of the running hosting system. The first command I would think of is `uname -s`. But I want to target some platform that is not available on my machine right now (like Cygwin, MinGW,...) and I want to make sure that I wrote the right name in the `if` condition. So the question is that how I can list all possible values of `uname -s` command (to avoid the headache for the wrong condition and who knows what's next...), and even for some commands which have the same characteristics?

Comment: You can't. That info is not built into the command. It reads it from the system it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after posting the question, I found out that there is a wiki page about the command `uname` which gives pretty much the information I need :D Never know that Wiki can be useful like that in this case